# select set of data containts in a specifc row mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two select queries.

Query 1

```
select value, id from attributes where nodeId in (select id from nodes where imageGenerated = 0 and projectId = 49) 
and name = "basename";
```

form this query im getting some string values for 'value' ex: BE3455444 kindof. and i want to get the rows from query 2 which has those 'value' include in 'content' column, below is my query 2

query 2

Comment: give us the tables and column names by editing the question, please.

Comment: @Shawn Mehan I've updated

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JOIN` with `LIKE`, e.g.

```
SELECT b.id, b.content
FROM blocks b JOIN attributes a ON b.content LIKE CONCAT('%', a.value, '%')
JOIN nodes n ON a.nodeId = n.id
WHERE n.imageGenerated = 0 AND n.projectId = 49;
```

Comment: pls
 
can you kindly check my question again, i've update query 2 with find int set how can I proceed above query with that. pls advice

Comment: @hansisilva I can't see query 2 now, anyway, the above should work.